# a question on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

Can anyone tell me why
$$1/2+\cos x+\cos 2x+\cdots+\cos nx=\frac{\sin((n+1/2)x)}{2\sin (x/2)}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: I think this question has appeared a few times before?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $2\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\cdot \cos (nx)=\sin \left(\frac{(2n+1)x}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{(2n-1)x}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

$2\sin(\frac{x}{2})*\cos(nx) = \sin((n+\frac{1}{2})x)-\sin((n-\frac{1}{2})x)$

it cancel each other out